# How to Pass a Generic List object to other Activity to another Activity in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, parcelable

I Tried making a Parcelable class but the `WriteToList` method only takes `non generic List`, how to properly pass the generic List to other activity ?

```
public class ParceableTextBlock : TextBlock, IParcelable
{
    public override IList<IText> Components { get; }

    protected ParceableTextBlock(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference,transfer)
    {

    }

    public int DescribeContents()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public void WriteToParcel(Parcel dest, [GeneratedEnum] ParcelableWriteFlags flags)
    {
        dest.WriteList(Components);
    }
}
```

[image]

I tried the below code before trying to make a `Parcelable` class

```
List<TextBlock> blocks = new List<TextBlock>();
Intent drawviewIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(SomeActivity));
            drawviewIntent.PutExtra("Blocks", blocks);
```

[image]

TextBlock class

```
[Register("com/google/android/gms/vision/text/TextBlock", DoNotGenerateAcw = true)]
public class TextBlock : Java.Lang.Object, IText, IJavaObject, IDisposable
{
    protected TextBlock(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer);

    public virtual Rect BoundingBox { get; }
    public virtual IList<IText> Components { get; }
    public virtual string Language { get; }
    public virtual string Value { get; }
    protected override IntPtr ThresholdClass { get; }
    protected override Type ThresholdType { get; }

    [Register("getCornerPoints", "()[Landroid/graphics/Point;", "GetGetCornerPointsHandler")]
    public virtual Point[] GetCornerPoints();
}
```

Comment: use `putExtra(String name, Parcelable[] value)` or `putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)`

Comment: Problem is the generic item is Not parcelable, the item is a interface object. i have to make so many parcelable custom classes and extend their classes that way. please check `IList<IText> Components`, `IText` is not parcelable

Comment: you can only pass either `Parcelable` or `Serializable` classes

Comment: Ohk, thank you i will try Serializable

Answer (score 2):

You can add a NuGet Pakeage named Newtonsoft.Json,then you can pass the List like this:

```
   List<TextBlock> blocks = new List<TextBlock>();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SomeActivity));
            intent.PutExtra("Blocks", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(blocks));
            StartActivity(intent);
```

and you can get the List like this:

```
  var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TextBlock>>(Intent.GetStringExtra("Blocks"));
```

Comment: There is a constructor inside the TextBlock, it is giving this error `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unable to find a constructor to use for type Android.Gms.Vision.Texts.TextBlock. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path '[0]', line 1, position 3.`

Comment: After creating a new class and extending `TextBlock` it gives this error 'Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  error: constructor TextBlock in class TextBlock cannot be applied to given types;
public class TextBlockNew
  required: SparseArray<zzdcs>
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length MyProject D:\MyProject\MyProject\obj\Debug\81\android\src\md50f9025d5d8891f94a2ab033e649179cc\TextBlockNew.java 4'

Comment: Updated the Question wth Textblock class

Comment: try to add an empty constructor in the class,could it run?

Comment: no it doesnt, but i am trying to serialize `SparseArray` i will get back, do i have to add `Serializable` attribute to classes ?

Comment: in native Android,the classes need to implements Serializable,but in Xamarin Android i have never try it . But i think"JsonConvert.SerializeObject(blocks)"  have done this for us.However i will have a try ! If no better way to pass ,maybe you could make the List static.